# How to get values from a java class android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want help in my MembersActivity, here I want to list all my members from a company that is logged in but first I have to check in which company my logged user belongs.
In my register activity, I create a new company

```
//send data
ArrayList<Company> companies= new ArrayList<Company>();
Company company = new Company(namecompany,m,e,d,p,null);
companies.add(company);

FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

databaseReference.child("companies").child(user.getUid()).setValue(company);
```

And in my MembersActivity i want to get all members from the company that the user that is logged in belongs.

```
//USER LOGGED IN - IT WORKS

firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        Intent i= new Intent(this, FeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userEmail = user.getEmail(); //email util log
```

Now I want to check in which company this user belongs. I do this but it shows that my companies array is empty

```
private ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

for(int i = 0; i < companies.size(); i++)
    {
        Company company = companies.get(i);
        Log.d("GoWeb", "membro: "+ company.getMembers());
    }
```

How can I check in which company the user logged in belongs and then list all the members from that company?

I'm using Firebase form my database.
This is my database:

- Companies

  - id_company
  - nameCompany
  - logoCompany
  - members

    - 0

      - emailM
      - nameM
      - nameCompany
      - pontM
      - typeM
      - photoM

Comment: Follow this link to store array in firebase https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html but i think you should store data  an object, keyed by unique ids ,

Comment: Where did you get a non empty list for `companies`? Why wouldn't it be empty other than that one place that you added to it?

Comment: you have to learn to flatten your data in firebase. With a flattened database each member node will have a list of all the companies he/she belongs to and each company node will have a list of its members. please read this blog https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data